# Nested fragment improper layout inflation in TabLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

So I have a `main_activity` with `DrawerLayout`. This activity has `FrameLayout` which is inflated with the layout of `fragment_forecast`. `Fragment_forecast` has `TabLayout`which holds three other fragments. All of this child fragment layouts overlap tabs of `TabLayout`.[image]

I tried to use LinearLayout instead of FrameLayout inside fragment_forecast but the result is that bottom part of child_fragments is cut off.

What is a proper way to handle this situation ?

Activity layout for `main_activity`:

```
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.daza.soundmap.Main2Activity">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_activity_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Fragment layout for `fragment_day_forecast` (child of forecast_fragment) :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.daza.soundmap.ForecastFragment">


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabBackground="@color/primaryLightColor"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/secondaryColor"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/primaryTextColor" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />

</FrameLayout>
```

Fragment layout for `fragment_day_forecast`:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.daza.soundmap.DayForecastFragment"
   >

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout_hour"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view_hour_forecast"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TabLayout` is overlapping with `ViewPager` `Fragment` because Your parent of `fragment_day_forecast` is

- FrameLayout

  - TabLayout
  - ViewPager

Where `FrameLayout` is meant to put one `View` over another.

You need to use `RelativeLayout` as a parent view. i.e., Set relation between views. In this case, It will be `ViewPager` below `TabLayout`.
Something like(fragment_day_forecast),

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.daza.soundmap.ForecastFragment">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabBackground="@color/primaryLightColor"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/secondaryColor"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/primaryTextColor" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/tabs" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please up-vote this answer, If helped. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

Try this bunch of code. Replace FragmentLayout with RelativeLayout and set viewpager below id tabs .

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```